# creating notifications in ios that cannot be removed by user

Tags: ios, notifications

I am using android phone in which i am using an app named "Smart App Protector". When i launch the application a notification comes as "Smart App Protector is running". Here i could not remove the notification manually by swiping right or left (i could remove other notifications regarding mails, tweets, etc.,). I found that its designed in such a way that in order to remove the notification from my notification center i have to click the notification and launch the application and then disable the app so that notification gets removed (I guess that they have coded in a way that notification is removed by stopping the application). 
     Now i am seeking a way to implement this in my iphone application. Before that i want to know whether it is possible in ios or not. Some freaks in ios out there, Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this on iOS. Notifications are there to alert the user to a small amount of information, not to force their behaviours.

Edit: You cannot do this on stock iOS, jailbroken iOS is another story.